# Post process MongoDB document before saving a Spring Data MongoDB entity

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on a service that stores object entities in a MongoDB database. The entities (Java classes) come from a context that I cannot change.

I would like to add time information to the mapped MongoDB documents, without embedding the entities in a special wrapper class.

I know that I don't get the time information back when reading the data via the Java entity. Since the information is only needed for internal purposes (e.g. TTL index) this is no problem for me.

Is there a way to do the entity-document mapping and then post process the result (BSON document) before saving it to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to [`BeforeSaveEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/BeforeSaveEvent.html) as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#mongodb.mapping-usage.events) which is given the original entity and the already mapped `Document`.

Comment: That's great but I did not manage to get this work with BulkOperations :-| Is it supported on BulkInserts? I do very generic inserts like `bukOps.insert(List<Object>).execute();`.

Comment: That's a bug. I've created [DATAMONGO-2290](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAMONGO/issues/DATAMONGO-2290) for you.

Comment: Great. Thanks Oliver.